# Is there a Gigabit switch in packet tracer (more than two gigabit ports)?

Tags: cisco, packet-tracer

I am trying to configure a packet tracer based on a scenario. I am wondering if there is a way to get a GigabitEthernet 0/5 and a GigabitEthernet 0/6 interface on any of the switches?

I have tried them all with no luck, and there is no expansion options to meet the requirement.

Suggestions are much appreciated

Comment: Seems not (to my surprise I must admit), but what for? Since this is only an emulator in which you can't push traffic, there's no difference between fastethernet and gigabitethernet ports. It would be only a cosmetic  difference.

Comment: Packet Tracer is very limited because it is only intended to get you through the CCNA exam.

Comment: Hm my previous comment was wrong (see [fracjackmac answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/68387/16930)).

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

I have a copy of PacketTracer, Version 7.2.0.0226, that contains a 3650-24PS Multi-Layer Switch with twenty-eight (28) Gig ports...

- 1/0/1 - 1/0/24 (fixed copper)
- 1/1/1 - 1/1/4 (copper or fiber SFPs)